# Automatically update label every second

Tags: c#

So I'm trying to make a clicker game and I've set a timer to the Factory upgrade. The cookies update, but in the background.

The label does not update until you click the `Main` button (to raise cookie count). I tried `CookieCount.Refresh()` or `Refresh()` (`CookieCount` being the label I want to update every second).

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    TRIPLECBTN.Hide();

    // Create a timer with a ten second interval.
    aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);

    aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);

    // Set the Interval to 2 seconds (2000 milliseconds).
    aTimer.Interval = 1000;
    aTimer.Enabled = false;
}
public void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    cookies = cookies + 1;
}
public void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cookies >= 1)
    {
        FACTORYBTN.Hide();
        INFO1.Hide();
        COST1.Hide();
        PRICE1.Hide();
        cookies -= 250;
        MessageBox.Show("You have bought Factory!");
        aTimer.Enabled = true;

    }
}
```

(there are some lines in between but they aren't important).

Comment: WinForms should use a WinForms timer.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? What works and what does not?

Comment: The label doesnt update every time a cookie is added (every second) unless you click the button which increases the cookie count. But it does count them in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the label in the OnTimedEvent where you count up your cookies.

```
  public void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
  {
      cookies = cookies + 1;
      label.Text = YourText
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! Haven't thought of that :s

Comment: No problem. Please mark this as answer if you don't have more questions